# What are the default attributes values of tags

Tags: html

Is there any reference that shows the default attributes values of some tags? For example if I write:

```
<form>
...
</form>
```

It rendered to something like this: (I think)

```
<form action="" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
...
</form>
```

Or `<input></input>` is rendered to `<input type="text"></input>`

Where I can find this information for all tags?

Comment: Go to http://www.w3.org/ and search your tag. Then you find all references and default attributes etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The W3C reference is probably your best bet.

- For HTML 4: http://w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3
- For HTML 5: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element

Generally, a quick way to find the right page is to Google (as pointed out by @DTDesign)

```
<name of the element> site:w3.org
```

just skip the w3schools garbage, look for `w3.org` hits, and you're on your way.

Comment: If you want only hits from a specific site, search in google like `site:w3.org` and then your tag. So it displays only results by w3.org

Comment: All HTML5 elements with their abailable attributes are listed here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1. The HTML 4 spec is now more like history because HTML5 becomes the default (and only) standard for browser vendors.